# Unable to init from given URL, Intervention Image, Laravel queued job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I have queued job, which saves images from given URLs (gets them from remote and saves in local) and everything works, but, if I put this code inside a queued job, I am getting an error.

> local.ERROR: Unable to init from given URL (URL which exists and I can access via browser )...

I can access these URLs, `allow_url_fopen` is enabled, and this code works without a queued job.

```php
try {
    $img = Image::make($photo->url);
    $img->save($path.$filenameBig); // Save the big image
} catch (NotReadableException $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

This `$photo->url` is `http` and I can see it in the error (it is not empty or something). I can access with a browser to the actual image. I am importing `Image` like this:

Use alias in `config/app`:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic::class,
```

In provider (same file):

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Then use it:

```
use Image;
```

**Stacktrace**

```
ErrorException: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/myes8adq/app/Libraries/PropertyLibrary.php:156
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions-handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/home/myes8adq/...', 156, Array)
#1 /home/myes8adq/app/Libraries/PropertyLibrary.php(156): file_get_contents('https://dummyim...')
#2 /home/myes8adq/app/Libraries/PropertyLibrary.php(30): App\Libraries\PropertyLibrary->importOneChanged(Object(stdClass))
#3 /home/myes8adq/app/Jobs/ImportPropertiesAndNomenclaturesJob.php(48): App\Libraries\PropertyLibrary->importAllChanged()
#4 [internal function]: App\Jobs\ImportPropertiesAndNomenclaturesJob->handle()
#5 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#7 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#9 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#10 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\ImportPropertiesAndNomenclaturesJob))
#11 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\ImportPropertiesAndNomenclaturesJob))
#12 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\ImportPropertiesAndNomenclaturesJob), false)
#14 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(88): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#15 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(327): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#16 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(277): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#17 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(230): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#18 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJob('redis', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#19 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#21 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#22 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#23 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#24 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#25 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#26 /home/myes8adq/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#27 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#28 /home/myes8adq/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(917): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /home/myes8adq/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(269): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/myes8adq/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /home/myes8adq/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /home/myes8adq/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 {main}
```

Comment: If it only fails when in the queue then it must be an issue with your queue workers. Have you restarted them since updating your code? Can you `file_get_contents()` the url?

Comment: Yes, and I have changed even URL to some of online services for generating fake images. The result is the same.

Comment: can you share the image link?

Comment: https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff

Comment: I have edited and the question with more info. I think this is more image library issue.

Comment: Seems that the problem is when the queued job is running `allow_url_fopen` is disable, but it is enabled, if I don't use queued jobs.

Comment: Can you provide the full error (with stack trace) of your queue worker as well?

Comment: ok, done, but it is ugly.

Comment: The problem is that I can access `file_get_content` with file via HTTP and it works. This property is enabled in my config, too.

Comment: The important bit is that queue workers, which run as CLI application, use another `php.ini` than your webserver.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It uses global php.ini, but how this problem is solved, because (I guess), it must be well know problem, with well known solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run supervisor with a allow_url_fopen=On

```
command=php -d allow_url_fopen=On ...
```

Comment: It is shared hosting

Comment: What php -r 'echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");' shows?

Comment: Somehow it loads global server php.ini, which I CAN'T change, because it is shared hosting, but these settings are in local php.ini file (where it is allowed) for my account. Now, the question is how to set that local php.ini file in the configuration for queued jobs.

Comment: Did you try to set it in your queue code? ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1); before the  $img = Image::make($photo->url);

Comment: Yes, but this setting cannot be set within PHP code.

Comment: Does php -c path/to/correct/php.ini make sense? Use cURL to download image?

Comment: cURL yes, but I need to use Intervention Image library

Answer (score 1):

If you are on shared hosting and cannot `allow_url_fopen` in your queue workers, then you may be able to download the image locally via cURL or GuzzleHTTP and then use `Image::make()` on the local file.

e.g.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/img.jpg";
if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen') && function_exists('curl_version')) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

} else if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
} else {
    echo 'No dice.';
}

$i= Image::make($content);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be the last solution, that I will try, but it is more work and more delay I guess. I think, there must be another way, how others do that on shared hosting, because everywhere this option is disabled globally in this type of hosting.